# onclick slideToggle + scrollTo DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple function that slideToggle() a hidden div and scrolls a div to the top. The slideToggle works ok, the scroll to top doesn't work at all.

Any hints?
My idea is that when the scrollTo function ends then starts the slideToggle one.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".more-about", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideToggle(800),
    $(this).parent().find('.more').hide(),
    $('.whole').scrollTo('#about', 100)
});
```

```css
.more-about {
  cursor: pointer
}

.hide {
  color: red;
  display: none
}

.whole {
  background: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="whole">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborum."<br><br>
  <div class="more-about">MORE</div>
  <div class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


</div>
```

Comment: scrollTo is not a function

Comment: There is no element with ID `about` in your code (which you use in your function)

Answer (score 0):

Updated: $('.whole').scrollTop('#about', 100)

There is no `#about` in your dom.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".more-about", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideToggle(800),
    $(this).parent().find('.more').hide(),
    $('.whole').scrollTop('#about', 100)
});
```

```css
.more-about {
  cursor: pointer
}

.hide {
  color: red;
  display: none
}

.whole {
  background: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="whole">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborum."<br><br>
  <div class="more-about">MORE</div>
  <div class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to show the hidden content on click of more and scroll to the position of the new content, here is the bin -- http://jsbin.com/wigojowabu/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
$(document).on("click", ".more-about", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideToggle(800);
    $(this).hide();
    window.scrollTo(0,$('#about').offset().top);
});
```

I have used window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos) to scroll to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animate()` and `scrollTop` inside for auto scroll in the good section. Please try bellow:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".more-about", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideToggle(800)
    $(this).parent().find('.more').hide()
    $('html').animate( { scrollTop: ($(".whole").scrollTop()+$(".more-about").offset().top) }, 1000 );
});
```

```css
.more-about {
  cursor: pointer
}

.hide {
  color: red;
  display: none
}

.whole {
  background: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="whole">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborum."<br><br>
  <div class="more-about">MORE</div>
  <div class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


</div>
```